Issue with LaTeX text in y-label when it is rotated in python
When I was trying to create pdf figures for latex in matplotlib, I came across weird behavior that altered text depending on whether it was rotated or not. I will attach minimum replication examples below.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "serif"
for rotation in [0, 90]:
    plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], label='data')
    plt.ylabel("y-label", rotation=rotation)
    plt.xlabel("x-label")
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(f"yLabelIssue_{rotation}.pdf")

This will save two figures, one where the y-label is rotated 90 degrees (as desired), but the label is in a different font/seems to be thinner, and the other where the y-label is horizontal, and a normal font.
Even more confusingly, when I replaced the ".pdf" extension with ".png", the issue also vanished, although I do not want to use a png for obvious reasons.
I tried the above block of code and was expecting to see the same font in both rotated and unrotated y-labels, but instead, the 90-degree rotated label is much thinner.
I cannot attach images, because SO does not support PDF, so instead here are some screenshots:


